# Store references inside a struct

Tags: rust, struct, lifetime

I got stuck with an issue about how to use references and lifetimes within a struct.

I have following constellation:

```
struct Item { ... }

struct Container {
    items: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Item>>>,
    active_item: RefMut<Item>,
}
```

There's a collection of "Item" where I'm going to select an active one which will be modified.
To simplify things I wanted to store a mutable reference to the active Item to avoid taking from the list and the RefCell every time. But storing a RefMut requires a lifetime parameter, so my struct would look like this:

```
struct Container<'a> {
    items: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Item>>>,
    active_item: RefMut<'a, Item>,
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the lifetime parameter when just referencing within the struct? Or something like a 'self lifetime, so I don't need to expose the lifetime parameter to the outside? None of the items in the List are referenced outside the struct. Also I don't necessarily need Rc or RefCell if it can be done without them.

Thank you

Comment: What you are trying to do is to create a self-referential struct (have a field referring to other fields). You really shouldn't do that, there are many problems with it. Maybe you could just store an index (position in the vector) of an active item instead?

Comment: Yes, already expected something like that. An index would be possible, but when I did something like that in C++ a (shared) pointer felt more safe because an index may become out of range.

Comment: _"To simplify things I wanted to store a mutable reference..."_ - experience says that this is your problem. Storing mutable references will only complicate things.

Comment: Don't store a `RefMut`, instead have `active_item: Rc<RefCell<Item>>` and only call `borrow_mut` when you really need to mutate the item.

Comment: @PeterHall I don't think the duplicate is completely warranted, he doesn't *really* store a reference, he just uses `Rc` incorrectly. Using `Rc` in this case absolutely makes this usecase possible.

Comment: @SvenSteiner I fully agree with Jmb, you can't store `RefMut`, you need to store an instance of the `Rc` instead. Apart of that, your situation is a valid usecase for `Rc`.